# How do I create columns differently depending on vendor in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying not to write models vendor specifically for cross-vendor(?) support and stuck with column option that is same feature but under different name. For example, utf8_binary collation is needed on a column for performance issue and case-sensitivity, but names are different depending on vendor.

I know the best way is to avoid such types and options when considering cross-vendor but when vendor-specific option is inevitable, is there any SQLAlchemy implementation of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the column option in a vendor specific configuration file like:

```
col_options = {'collation': 'utf8_binary'}
```

Then use it in your model definition like this:

```
name = Column('name', String(**col_options))
```

The `**` will map all the key/value pairs in col_options onto String as keyword arguments.

Comment: In addition, just define your vendor-specific type and import them from different module based on vendor configuration: `KeyCodeColumnType = String(**col_options)` and use it where appropriate. This will reduce duplication and make refactoring much easier.